# retruning list of ID, based off Boolean values

Tags: r

I would like to find out the list of ID's, when observations of  the variable contains `True`.

The data's format contains the variable name and the date. The real date ranges from 2018-2021. and contains many a over million observation. I made up a rough sample.

```
df1 <- data.frame(accountID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
              var1_2018_1 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_2 = c('F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_3 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_4 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_5 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_6 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_7 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_8 = c('F', 'F', 'T', 'F', 'T'),
              var1_2018_9 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_10 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_11 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'),
              var1_2018_12 = c('T', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'T'))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::across`:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(across(.cols = !is.numeric,.fns =  ~ .x == 'T'))
```

Output:

```
  accountID var1_2018_1 var1_2018_2 var1_2018_3 var1_2018_4 var1_2018_5 var1_2018_6 var1_2018_7
1         5           T           T           T           T           T           T           T
  var1_2018_8 var1_2018_9 var1_2018_10 var1_2018_11 var1_2018_12
1           T           T            T            T            T
```

Then to get IDs:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(across(.cols = !is.numeric,.fns =  ~ .x == 'T')) %>% 
  select(accountID) %>% 
  pull()
```

Output:

```
[1] 5
```

And without `pull`:

```
  accountID
1         5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lapply` to get the *ID* when an observations is `TRUE` by using the logical vector to subset *accountID*.

```
lapply(df1[-1], function(i) df1$accountID[i])
#$var1_2018_1
#[1] 1 4 5
#
#$var1_2018_2
#[1] 4 5
#
#$var1_2018_3
#[1] 1 4 5
#...
```

In case the columns are not logical (like in the given example data) and hold characters, it could be converted with:

```
df1[-1] <- lapply(df1[-1], '==', "T")
```